# Matplotlib plot_surface mplot3d with masked array and custom palette gives wrong color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a surface in 3D using mplot3D from matplotlib. I want a custom color palette where values above 1.0 are green, below -1.0 are blue, exactly 0.0 are red(invalid values) and all other values according to a greyscale. I've been able to get all of these right except for the condition that 0.0 should be red. Following [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_masked.html) I thought I may be able to set 0.0 as the "bad value" in a masked array but it fails.

This is the snippet where I try to plot my values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

...

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
masked_array = np.ma.masked_equal(Z,0.0)
palette = cm.gray
palette.set_over('g', 1.0)
palette.set_under('b', 1.0)
palette.set_bad('r', 1.0)

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,masked_array,
    rstride=1,
    cstride=1,
    cmap=palette,
    norm = colors.Normalize(vmin = -1.0, vmax = 1.0, clip = False))
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Now I run this with Z set to a 2D numpy array with many 0.0 values:

```
>>> print Z == 0.0
[[False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]]
```

And I expect to get a surface with many red squares. Instead I get this:

[image]

Can anyone help explain this or help me achieve the same effect in some other way? To clarify, I want z-values that are equal to 0.0 to be marked as invalid by coloring them red while the rest of the graph should follow the greyscale palette.

Comment: Why should 0 be an invalid value?

Comment: @MaxNoe in my original Z 2D array I had a lot of NaN:s. In this particular visualization it would make sense to plot those at the z=0 plane but with another color to distinguish them from values that are just very close to 0. Since Z originally had no values that were exactly 0, I replaced the NaN:s with 0:s and tried to mask all values in Z exactly equal to 0.0 as "bad".

Comment: A, my bad. Overlooked the masked Array. It works for me when I do a 2d plot with `plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)`. The 3d axes seems to not support these masked arrays.

Comment: Yes, there is an old old issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/487) that is still open regarding plot_surface() and masked arrays, so it looks like this is still on the wishlist for 3D axes.